# Show that $([A,A])$ contains the identity matrix.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $A = M_n(C)$, $n \geq 1$, where $C$ is a commutative unital ring. If $n \geq 2$, then $([A,A])$, the ideal generated by $[A,A]$, contains the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Revised)
Step 1:It is easy to prove that $E_{ij}\in [A,A]$ for all $i\neq j$. Also $E_{ii}-E_{jj}\in [A,A]$.

Step 2: Using step 1, let's prove that $E_{ii}\in ([A,A])$.

Step 3: Using step 2, it is easy to prove that $I\in ([A,A])$.

Just please use different $E_{ij}$ to obtain all of these..Also we have two sided ideals.:)

Comment: I was trying that route, can I have another tip to prove that $E_{ii} \in [A,A].$

Comment: @Croos Sorry my first answer is wrong. Note that any element of $[A,A]$ has trace 0. So it is impossible for $E_{ii}$ to be an element of $[A,A]$.

Comment: I can do $E_{ii}(E_{ii} - E_{jj}) = E_{ii} \in ([A,A])$, where $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $i \neq j$

Comment: Is it solved now, may I ask?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.